# when i use FFmpeg libary to compress video,ide show this error

Tags: android, ffmpeg

```
 E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: /data/user/0/com.example/files/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20170517_112234.mp4 -vf scale=500:-1 qscale:v 8 -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4/storage/emulated/0/wobingwoyi/1496060268815.mp4

 java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/com.wobingwoyi/files/ffmpeg, -y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20170517_112234.mp4, -vf, scale=500:-1, -qscale:v, 8, -acodec, copy, -vcodec, mpeg4, /storage/emulated/0/wobingwoyi/1496060268815.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

[Here is my Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybQZf.png)

[This is the complete error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OepGM.png)

Comment: Please, sort the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your library in not complete, the log shows that:`No such file or directory`. Checking the folder in the `libs`, make sure that it all has a `.so` file.

[image]

There are two ways to solve this problem :

- 1. **Supply all library file**
- 2. Make you library file match you abiFilters(the library in `libs` has a `.so` file).

[image]